# POST data within DownloadStringAsync

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webclient

I have to download some data from external source but I have to submit which data I want to retrieve, I'm using special url (on website) routing and I don't allow special characters in URL so I guess I have to use POST or GET method to submit data. How to achieve this with Download String Async?

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
c.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCompleted);
c.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uristring));
```

As you can see I'm currently downloading default data only.

Comment: I would encourage you to take a look at new HttpClient (using PostAsync) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably to use `UploadStringAsync` or `UploadDataAsync`, having attached the appropriate event handlers.